# Where do I put my view data?

Tags: vue.js, architecture, vuejs2, store

Okay, let's say I have this store.state:

```
{
  inventories: {},
  items: {
    types: ['Generator', 'Gearbox', 'Dynamo'],
    qualities: ['S', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
  },
}
```

A few components later, I have this view:

```
<div class="Item">
  <strong class="Item-prop Item-name">{{ item.type }}</strong>
  <span class="Item-prop Item-quality">{{ item.quality }}</span>
</div>
```

Now, instead of a `div`, I would like to display a `svg`, with its content depending on the state. For example, display a cog when `type == 'Gearbox'`.

Where do I put this definition ? In the store ? Or in my **Item** component ?

See, I could put this in the view, but then I would repeat spelling out each item type.

I could put this in the store.state, but... its view stuff, right ?

PS: I am *not* at Vuex stage yet, this is a custom store

Comment: If it is dynamic then store is the way to go.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point.